# How to force Ubuntu/Debian/Mint to unload modules at suspend-to-disk?

Tags: linux, freeze, suspend, kernel-module

I put a DVB-T card into the computer, and now the system hangs at suspend to disk. CTRL-ALT-DEL does not work, hard reset is necessary.

I have a faint memory of the trick being to remove the modules at suspend and reload at resume. I can neither google nor remember how to do it.

Any hints, links and the like are appreciated.

PS I've tried `rmmod dvb_bt8xx`, but the system hung anyway - will the system suspend at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had issues with this before with wireless drivers, I think that I edited my `/etc/pm/config.d/modules` with the following:

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="dvb_bt8xx othermodulehere"
```

Hopefully I recall that correctly - that is assuming you use `pm-utils`.

Comment: The syntax must be different, because it didn't work with two modules, but with a single module the suspend works.